# Can't load custom library created with dojo build

Tags: build, dojo, load

I have created an application which has its own set of dojo widgets. I have created a custom dojo build to pack all my library in a single dojo file.

The file has a mix of AMD and non-AMD classes. In fact just one AMD class. I am using dojo 1.7.4 for building although the runtime server is using 1.7.2. I have parseOnLoad=false. This is a must for my WebSphere Portal runtime.

The library has a set of declare, define, provide ... something like:

```
require({cache:{
'com/gnf/class1':function(){
// wrapped by build app
define("com/gnf/class1", ["dijit","dojo","dojox"], function(dijit,dojo,dojox){

dojo.provide("com.gnf.class1");

dojo.declare("com.gnf.class1", null, {
});
(function(){
    if( com.gnf.class1.instance == undefined ){
        com.gnf.class1.instance = new com.gnf.class1(); 
    }
})();

});

}, 
'com/gnf/class2':function(){
// wrapped by build app
define("com/gnf/class2", ["dijit","dojo","dojox","dojo/require!com/ibm/btt/util/I18nUtil,com/ibm/btt/util/StringUtil"], function(dijit,dojo,dojox){

dojo.provide("com.gnf.dijit.class2"); 

dojo.require("com.gnf.util.class3");
dojo.require("com.gnf.util.class4");

dojo.declare("com.gnf.dijit.class2", null,{
}

...

}});
define("com/gnf/app/app", [], 1);
```

I then include this generated js file in my JSP page using

```
<script type="..." src="/js/app.js"> </script>
```

The file is loaded and I can see by using Firebug that the code is executed stoping in each declaration. But, no innner code is executed. 
In the end, my set of classes is not available and I receive "class not found" error messages.

Any ideas? How should I load my library? Is there something missing?

Thanks in advance.